# How can I track the lyrics of a song and get the String of lyrics in specific time[00:00:000] in my musicPlayerApp in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, avplayer

Here is my json file:

```
{
"duration": 198,
"file": "https://grepp-programmers-challenges.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/2020-flo/music.mp3",
"lyrics": "[00:16:200]we wish you a merry christmas [00:18:300]we wish you a merry christmas [00:21:100]we wish you a merry christmas [00:23:600]and a happy new year [00:26:300]we wish you a merry christmas [00:28:700]we wish you a merry christmas [00:31:400]we wish you a merry christmas [00:33:600]and a happy new year [00:36:500]good tidings we bring [00:38:900]to you and your kin [00:41:500]good tidings for christmas [00:44:200]and a happy new year [00:46:600]Oh, bring us some figgy pudding [00:49:300]Oh, bring us some figgy pudding [00:52:200]Oh, bring us some figgy pudding [00:54:500]And bring it right here [00:57:000]Good tidings we bring [00:59:700]to you and your kin [01:02:100]Good tidings for Christmas [01:04:800]and a happy new year [01:07:400]we wish you a merry christmas [01:10:000]we wish you a merry christmas [01:12:500]we wish you a merry christmas [01:15:000]and a happy new year [01:17:700]We won't go until we get some [01:20:200]We won't go until we get some [01:22:800]We won't go until we get some [01:25:300]So bring some out here [01:29:800]연주 [02:11:900]Good tidings we bring [02:14:000]to you and your kin [02:16:500]good tidings for christmas [02:19:400]and a happy new year [02:22:000]we wish you a merry christmas [02:24:400]we wish you a merry christmas [02:27:000]we wish you a merry christmas [02:29:600]and a happy new year [02:32:200]Good tidings we bring [02:34:500]to you and your kin [02:37:200]Good tidings for Christmas [02:40:000]and a happy new year [02:42:400]Oh, bring us some figgy pudding [02:45:000]Oh, bring us some figgy pudding [02:47:600]Oh, bring us some figgy pudding [02:50:200]And bring it right here [02:52:600]we wish you a merry christmas [02:55:300]we wish you a merry christmas [02:57:900]we wish you a merry christmas [03:00:500]and a happy new year"
}
```

and I parsed the data in *musicManager* in my project.
and I want to show the lyrics on *Main.Storyboard*.

I'm Streaming the audioFile with AVPlayer.

I parse the Json in musicManager through musicData to musicModel
then I'm willing to change the textLabel in textView in the UIViewController.

and here are my relevant code for **musicManager**.

```
import Foundation

protocol MusicManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateMusic(music: MusicModel)
}

struct MusicManager {
    
    let urlString = "https://grepp-programmers-challenges.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/2020-flo/song.json"
    
    var delegate: MusicManagerDelegate?
    
    func performRequest(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    
                    if let music = self.parseJSON(musicData: safeData) {
                        delegate?.didUpdateMusic(music: music)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(musicData: Data) -> MusicModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MusicData.self, from: musicData)
            
            let singer = decodedData.singer
            let album = decodedData.album
            let title = decodedData.title
            let imageURL = decodedData.image
            let fileURL = decodedData.file
            let duration = decodedData.duration
            let lyrics = decodedData.lyrics
    
            let music = MusicModel(currentSinger: singer, currentAlbum: album, currentTitle: title, currentImage: imageURL, currentFile: fileURL, currentDuration: duration, currentLyrics: lyrics)
            
            return music
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**musicData**

```
struct MusicData: Decodable {
    var singer: String
    var album: String
    var title: String
    var image: String
    var file: String
    var duration: Int
    var lyrics: String
    
}
```

**musicModel**

```
struct MusicModel {
    let currentSinger: String
    let currentAlbum: String
    let currentTitle: String
    let currentImage: String
    let currentFile: String
    let currentDuration: Int
    let currentLyrics: String
    
}
```

Comment: pls show us relevant codes from your musicManager class

Comment: I added relevant codes. thx for the help :) @mjoe7

Comment: Saw a related open source Swift project which you could use: [link](https://github.com/jayasme/SpotlightLyrics)

Comment: @mjoe7 Wow thx a lot! I'll try with it :) It really helped me out!